# how to nmap to show output text file has Discovered word and ip address and port for opened in window like in cmd?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, nmap

option -oG not suitable for Excel to extract value in window because all ports in on line and not allowed to use bash

i automate with batch file, but output not have Discovered starting word and follow a port number,
it is not like the output result in Zenmap or when run in cmd,
and since redirect operator can not be used with start command, 
i am forced to use option -o , but -o result text file is not the same as it 
show in console.

```
start nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn -p 1-5000 -iL IPaddr.txt -o Hello_Result.txt
start nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn -p 1-5000 -iL IPaddr.txt -o Hello_Result.txt
```

it show

```
443/tcp open ssl
```

but i expect

```
Discovered open port 443/tcp on x.x.x.x
```

Comment: is `start nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn -p 1-5000 -iL IPaddr.txt > Hello_Result.txt` produces the desired output ?

Comment: No, it show "443/tcp open ..." but i expect "Discovered open port 443/tcp on x.x.x.x"

Comment: sorry could'nt help it.. /(-_-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a non-blocking way to run `nmap` with `start`, try putting e.g. the command suggested in the comments in another batch file.

*nmap_example.bat*

```
nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn -p 1-5000 -iL IPaddr.txt > Hello_Result.txt
```

*master.bat*

```
start nmap_example.bat
@REM Do other stuff here
```

Note that you will still need to parse out the `Discovered open port YYY/tcp on X.X.X.X` lines from e.g. `Hello_Result.txt` (as you are capturing the entire `nmap` command-line output).